# Two divs not aligning horizontally in html with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am currently having an issue alligning two divs on my page. It works perfectly with three boxes, but when using a different width the vertical alignment is out by a few pixels.

When the PHP variable is set to 0 you see the div boxes aligned perfectly in the horizontal and vertical axes. BUt when you switch the PHP variable to 1 they align vertically (if more are added beneath the current one), but not horizontally.

How can this be setup so they are aligned perfectly?

Below is my CSS:

```
body {
   background-color:#FFFFFF;
   margin:0px;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   height:auto !important;
   height:100%;
   margin:0 auto -50px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
#nhHeader {
    background-color:#215967;
    width:100%;
}
#headerTitle {
   float:left;
   padding-left:5.5em;
   color:#FFFFFF;
}
#headerLinks {
   float:right;
   padding-right:1.5em;
   text-align:right;
   vertical-align:middle;
}
#nhBody {
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
}
#nhBodyHeader {
   float:left;
   padding-left:1em;
   display: table;
   width:100%;
}
#nhBodyMain {
   width:100%;
}
span.nhBodyHeaderText, span.nhBodyHeaderImage {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
span.nhBodyHeaderText {
   font-size:large;
   font-weight:bold;
}
.detailCellContainer2 {
   float:left;
   padding:1.6%;
   width:63%;
}
.detailCellContainer3 {
   float:left;
   padding:1.6%;
   width:33%;
}
.detailCell1Header, .detailCell2Header {
   color:#FFFFFF;
   font-size:1.5em;
   width:100%;
}
.detailCell1Header {
   background-color:#93CDDD;
}
.detailCell2Header {
   background-color:#215968;
}
.detailCellHeaderText {
   padding:0.5em;
}
.detailCellMainText {
   background-color:#DBEEF4;
   padding:1em;
}
```

Below is my HTML / PHP:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>NH Reporting</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='nh.css'>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id='container'>
        <div id='nhHeader'>
        <div id='headerTitle'>
            DSU Reporting
        </div>
        <div id='headerLinks'>
            Links
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id='nhBody'>
        <?php
            $i = 1;
            switch ($i) {
            case 0:
                //For Main:
                echo "<div id='nhBodyHeader'><span class='nhBodyHeaderImage'><img src='images/NHLogo.png'></span><span class='nhBodyHeaderText'>NH - Reporting Menu</span></div>";
                echo "<div id='nhBodyMain'>";
                echo "<div class='detailCellContainer3'>";
                    echo "<div class='detailCell1header'><div class='detailCellHeaderText'>Activity</div></div>";
                    echo "<div class='detailCellMainText'>Report 1<br>Report 2</div>";
                echo "</div>";

                echo "<div class='detailCellContainer3'>";
                    echo "<div class='detailCell1header'><div class='detailCellHeaderText'>Financials</div></div>";
                    echo "<div class='detailCellMainText'>Report 1<br>Report 2</div>";
                echo "</div>";

                echo "<div class='detailCellContainer3'>";
                    echo "<div class='detailCell1header'><div class='detailCellHeaderText'>Organisation</div></div>";
                    echo "<div class='detailCellMainText'>Report 1<br>Report 2</div>";
                echo "</div>";

                echo "<div class='detailCellContainer3'>";
                    echo "<div class='detailCell1header'><div class='detailCellHeaderText'>Workforce</div></div>";
                    echo "<div class='detailCellMainText'>Report 1<br>Report 2</div>";
                echo "</div>";

                echo "<div class='detailCellContainer3'>";
                    echo "<div class='detailCell1header'><div class='detailCellHeaderText'>Quality</div></div>";
                    echo "<div class='detailCellMainText'>Report 1<br>Report 2</div>";
                echo "</div>";

                echo "<div class='detailCellContainer3'>";
                    echo "<div class='detailCell2header'><div class='detailCellHeaderText'>My Recent Reports</div></div>";
                    echo "<div class='detailCellMainText'>Report 1<br>Report 2</div>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
                break;
            case 1:
                //For Drill-down
                echo "<div id='nhBodyHeader'><span class='nhBodyHeaderImage'><img src='images/NHLogo.png'></span><span class='nhBodyHeaderText'>Activity Reporting Menu</span></div>";
                echo "<div id='nhBodyMain'>";
                echo "<div class='detailCellContainer2'>";
                    echo "<div class='detailCellContainer1'>";
                    echo "<div class='detailCell1header'><div class='detailCellHeaderText'>Workforce</div></div>";
                    echo "<div class='detailCellMainText'>Report 1<br>Report 2</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";

                echo "<div class='detailCellContainer3'>";
                    echo "<div class='detailCellContainer1'>";
                    echo "<div class='detailCell1header'><div class='detailCellHeaderText'>Favourites</div></div>";
                    echo "<div class='detailCellMainText'>Report 1<br>Report 2</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
                break;
            case 2:
                //For Reports:
                echo "<iframe src='http://www.linkhere.com.au/reportXYZ' frameborder=0 height='100%' width='100%'></iframe>";
                break;
            }

        ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the problem:
[image: Image Version of Problem]

**EDIT 2014-02-13:** After some more digging I've found that it has to do with the width percentages of detailCellContainer2 and detailCellContainer3. I'm not too sure how to fix it, but if the percentages are the same they are displayed on the same level, if the percentages are different the smaller percentage is presented higher than the larger one (the larger the variance between the percentages the greater the difference in alignment).

Comment: please prepate fiddle for us boss

Comment: attach a image plzz...

Comment: I've attached an image, but I can't get fiddle's to work on my machine. Sadly corporate settings seem to be blocking it's functionality. I've uploaded an image though.

Comment: Now I understood the exact problem. Look at the top left corner of the pic :) #IE :)

Comment: Sadly IE is the default in the organisation. So it all has to be built with IE in mind. But thankfully most other browsers will display fine once developed right for IE.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
div.detailCellContainer3
{
  width:33%;
  display:inline;
}
```

Where detailCellContainer3 is class of div to be aligned horizontally.

Comment: Thanks, but when tried this didn't fix it at all. I know it has something to do with the different container as when there are three detailCellContainer3's they appear next to each other, but when using a detailCellContainer2 with a detailCellContainer3 they suddenly become disaligned.

Comment: then check width of detailCellContainer2 and add float left to each div including above so it becomes like  div.detailCellContainer3
{
width:33%;
display:inline; float:left;
}

Comment: Sadly I've tried this, but nothing has worked with it.

Please refer to "EDIT 2014-02-13" in the original post which describes that it has to do with the width, but i'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok well you won't be able to reproduce that php switch in JSFiddle, but I loaded everything into here with the first case: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MA945/)

From that I can tell that `#nhBodyMain` has a height of 0, which is being inherited from an ancestor element. So I think the issue here is that something isn't clearing above the two divs. Use dev tools to inspect and figure out why. You need something to clear between your divs. Perhaps something like this (except use an actual clearfix – Google it if you're unaware):

```
<div id="nhBodyHeader"><span class="nhBodyHeaderImage"><img src="images/NHLogo.png">                
</span><span class="nhBodyHeaderText">NH - Reporting Menu</span></div>
<div id="nhBodyMain">
<div class="detailCellContainer3">
<div class="detailCell1header"><div class="detailCellHeaderText">Activity</div></div>
<div class="detailCellMainText">Report 1<br>Report 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried searching ClearFix and the multiple different ones on Google haven't seemed to fix it. I can't see the JSFiddle, but based on your code above it looks like you've grabbed the main page (i = 0 in PHP) which contains three boxes on each line, but they line up perfectly. The one causing the issue is when using detailCellContainer2 with detailCellContainer3 (so when i = 1 in PHP) and the heading should be "Activity Reporting Menu".

Comment: Ok so I copied out the code again, but I'm clearly missing some of the base styles you have so it's hard to fully debug for you. I'm thinking that instead of using `float` you should look into giving the `display:inline-block` and make sure your percentages aren't adding up to more than 100%.

Comment: I tried with the CSS following, however it's still out by those few pixels.


.detailCellContainer2 {
   /*float:left;*/
   padding:1.6%;
   width:40%;
   display:inline;
   vertical-align:top;
}
.detailCellContainer3 {
   /*float:left;*/
   padding:1.6%;
   width:20%;
   display: inline;
   vertical-align:top;
}

Comment: Hmmm, what about wrapping .detailCellContainer2 and .detailCellContainer3 in a container div with `width: 100%; display: block;`?

Comment: They're already wrapped in a div (nhBodyMain) with the only property for that div a width of 100% (refer to the question above).

Comment: That's right. Ok, if you inspect element and remove the nhHeader node completely, do they line up then? If so, that's a start. Then try making nhBodyMain `display: block; clear: both;`. If they're not aligned, then something else is going on. Any way you can post all the applied CSS so I can replicate this? Could be anything – pseudo-elements, random styles overlapping, etc.